# How to get value from a cell in a row when a certain row is selected

Tags: javascript, html, mysql

I created the html and javascript to get the id of a row that contains different information for example I'll create a table below.

**id-----firstname   ----   lastname -------  product**
1------Jon            ---------------Doe    -------------     Apple
2      ----     Jane    -------------       Doe        ------------- Banana

When I click on the row I want that rows id to be selected.  I have the following code

```
alert(document.getElementById("id").value);

alert($(this).getElementbyId("id").value);//this line doesnt work
```

The first line will always come out to 1.  Or the id that is in the first field.  The second line doesn't do anything.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

---

Some HTML that is outputted

```
<table border=1 style="border-collapse: collapse">

<tr class='clickablerow'>
<td><textarea readonly cols='4' rows='1' id='id'>356</textarea></td> 
<td><textarea cols='20' rows='1' name='lastname'>Johnson</textarea></td> 
<td><textarea cols='20' rows='1' name='firstname'>Jon</textarea></td> 
<td><textarea cols='5' rows='1' name='room'>58B</textarea></td> 
<td><textarea cols='20' rows='1' name='product'>HP printer</textarea></td> 
<td><textarea cols='20' rows='1' name='problem'>lid is missing a part</textarea></td> 
<td><textarea cols='20' rows='1' name='finished'>5/16/2013</textarea></td> 
<td><textarea cols='20' rows='1' name='comments'>Fixed working now</textarea></td> 
</tr>
<tr class='clickablerow'><td><textarea readonly cols='4' rows='1' id='id'>429</textarea></td> 
<td><textarea cols='20' rows='1' name='lastname'>Harrison</textarea></td> 
<td><textarea cols='20' rows='1' name='firstname'>Wendy</textarea></td> 
<td><textarea cols='5' rows='1' name='room'>101</textarea></td> 
<td><textarea cols='20' rows='1' name='product'>Internet</textarea></td> 
<td><textarea cols='20' rows='1' name='problem'>Internet not working</textarea></td>
 <td><textarea cols='20' rows='1' name='finished'>5/24/2013</textarea></td> 
<td><textarea cols='20' rows='1' name='comments'>Need to change DNS</textarea></td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: IDs have to be unique (it seems like I write this 100 times a day). You can't have the same ID in each row.

Comment: My id is unique.  It auto increments.

Comment: He meant the id attribute in the textarea tag, that should be unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the table row to something like this:

```
<tr class='clickablerow'><td><textarea readonly cols='4' rows='1' class='id'>".$row['id']."</textarea></td>...</tr>
```

Use `class="id"` instead of `id="id"`, because you can't repeat IDs.

Then your JS code can be:

```
$("tr.clickablerow").click(function() {
    alert ($(this).find("textarea.id").val());
});
```

`$(this).getElementById("id").value` doesn't work because `$(this)` returns a jQuery object, not a DOM element. jQuery objects don't implement the same methods as DOM elements.

Comment: It doesn't display anything when I did that.

My class is named something else in order for the jQuery to work when I click it. I do set id with id, my code is below

echo "<tr class='clickablerow'><td><textarea readonly cols='4' rows='1' id='id'>".$row['id']."</textarea></td> ";

Comment: You can have multiple classes, or you can use that class in the code. It's just an example.

Comment: Please put your HTML in the question, instead of the text table.

Comment: It is the php within my HTML.  I am connecting to a database with MySQL to populate the table

Comment: Just show a little bit of the resulting HTML, which you can get from `View Source` in the browser.

Comment: Thank you so much it works.  I understand now.  Thanks for being patient with me.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if using jQuery is an option for you - but writing this down fairly quickly:

```
$("tr").click(function() {
     var currentID = $(this).attr("id");
     alert(currentID);
});
```

Explanation:
`$("tr").click()` - you are binding the click event to each `<tr>` element on your page (if you don't want every tr element to be bound to this event, you can add a class name to those you want to have triggered and use `$("tr.myClassName").click()` )

`$(this).attr("id")` - $(this) refers to the  element clicked. .attr("id") gets the tr's attribute value (in this case the "id" of the html element).

Hope that helps.

**UPDATE:**

I see that I have not understood the question clearly - thank you for bringing it to my attention - here is the amended sample:

```
$("tr").click(function() {
         var currentID = $("td textarea", this).val();
         alert(currentID);
});
```

Comment: No it says that it is undefined.  Thanks for your response though

Comment: He doesn't want to show the ID, he wants to show the value of the textarea.